# In couchbase what happen when you set PersistTo.NONE?

Tags: couchbase

I have a couchbase setting as follows

```
PersistTo.NONE;
ReplicateTo.NONE;
```

`ReplicateTo.NONE;` means it will not replicate to replica

But what does `PersistTo.NONE;` mean ? In the doc

https://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.7.15/com/couchbase/client/java/PersistTo.html#NONE

> Do not observe any disk persistence constraint.

But surely it persist to somewhere?

Does it observe durable write to disk or non durable write to memory (ie. server crash or restart will loose the data)?

Also it would seem that persistTo.One is very similar to replicateTo.One, what is the difference in this case, both observe replication to one replica?

Answer (score 3):

`PersistTo.NONE` + `ReplicateTo.NONE` means the client reports success as soon as the write is in memory on the node hosting the primary partition. This does not prevent the server from persisting and replicating the write.

As Matthew Groves commented, these options don't change the server's behavior. When you specify `PersistTo` and `ReplicateTo`, you're just asking the client to wait until it sees replication and persistence are complete before the client returns a "success" result.

Be aware that even if such a request completes successfully, there is no strong guarantee your write will survive a failover/rebalance scenario. For this reason, `PersistTo` and `ReplicateTo` are considered "legacy" options and are effectively deprecated.

Modern applications that have durability requirements should use [durable writes](https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/current/howtos/kv-operations.html#durability) instead.

> Also it would seem that persistTo.One is very similar to replicateTo.One, what is the difference in this case, both observe replication to one replica?

`ReplicateTo.ONE` waits until the document is in memory on the node hosting primary partition, and also in memory on least one node hosting a replica partition. When this is observed, you know the document is stored in memory on at least 2 nodes; it might not have been written to disk yet.

`PersistTo.ONE` waits until the document is written to disk on at least one node. It could be the node hosting the primary partition, or a node hosting a replica. When this is observed, you know the document is available on disk on at least 1 node (but maybe not the authoritative node).

If you specify *both* `PeristTo.ONE` and `ReplicateTo.ONE`, you know the document is on disk in at least one place, and in memory in at least two places.

This is all moot though, since as I mentioned above, PersistTo and ReplicateTo are effectively deprecated. They have the problem that even if you observe the requested replication and/or persistence, there's no strong guarantee that the replica that has your write will be the replica selected for promotion to "primary" (sometimes called "active") in the case of a failover.

When you absolutely cannot afford to lose a write, you should use [durable writes](https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/current/howtos/kv-operations.html#durability) instead, because they actually guarantee your writes survive failover/rebalance scenarios (up to a point, of course.)

Answer (score 2):

Taken in context :

> Insert a Document if it does not exist already and watch for durability constraints with the default key/value timeout.

The 'insert/upsert/replace/remove' call does not block until the durability constraint is met. The call returns immediately.

Comment: Yes, and just to put in my two cents, those settings don't mean data won't be persisted (written to disk) or replicated (copied to multiple nodes). It just means that the SDK will not sit and wait and confirm that it happened. Persistence and replication settings are on the bucket itself.

Comment: so what happen if you READ immediately after insert? If the insert is still in the process of committing what level of consistent read do you get?

Comment: If you read immediately with the kv api you will find it.  It will just not be persisted or replicated.

Comment: Just to restate my answer above - as I inferred information from my previous response :

If you read immediately with the kve api, you will find it, even though it  may not yet be persisted or replicated.

Comment: if the write is not persisted or replicated, is it possible subsequent read won't find the document, or there is a strong guarantee that document will be found even when its not persisted, for example during fail over .

Comment: > is it possible subsequent read won't find the document

You asked for "if you READ immediately" and that's what I answered.  If you wait a fraction of a second, it will likely be persisted and replicated.  The only way it would be lost is if the node crashed in the fraction of a second before it was persisted or replicated - if that's important then  use the appropriate option to persist and/or replicate during the insert/upsert/replace/delete operation.

Comment: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/buckets-memory-and-storage/vbuckets.html

Comment: @olaf if you are still confused, I'd be happy to get on a short zoom call or something, my email is matthew dot groves AT (the company name in question) dot com.